# How to handle tagging for Pandemic Legacy season 2?

Tags: discussion, tagging

In a few weeks, Pandemic Legacy Season 2 will be released. Based on the previews, it is pretty much an entirely different game from either Pandemic or Pandemic Legacy season 1. This is quite different from season 1, which was basically normal Pandemic with some additional mechanics.

Presumably we want a new tag for season 2. But what should it be? And should we alter the existing Pandemic Legacy tag to make it clear that those questions are about season 1?

Answer (score 6):

Done. May take a few minutes for caches to update. All 20 questions are now [pandemic-legacy-season-1](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pandemic-legacy-season-1).

---

Assuming the two do end up being very clearly different, I would favor [pandemic-legacy-season-1](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pandemic-legacy-season-1) and [pandemic-legacy-season-2](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pandemic-legacy-season-2). Might as well use the full names given by the publisher, and if we tried to keep [pandemic-legacy](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pandemic-legacy) for season 1, but add [pandemic-legacy-season-2](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pandemic-legacy-season-2), it'd just be confusing.

If people agree (I won't do this unilaterally) then I can go rename the existing tag before season 2 comes out, while it's easier because [pandemic-legacy](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pandemic-legacy) questions are all about season 1, not a mix of the two.

Comment: This would be my preference.

Comment: @bwarner Cool, I'll let it sit a couple days (looks like it doesn't release until the 26th so should be safe) just in case anyone has better colors to paint this bikeshed, and take care of it, say, Saturday if nothing came up. Feel free to ping me if it looks like I forgot.

Comment: @Jefromi This is your ping in case you forgot.

Comment: @diego I forgoooooot thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the [pandemic-legacy](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pandemic-legacy) tag should be modified to [pandemic-legacy-s01](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pandemic-legacy-s01) or [pandemic-legacy-season1](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pandemic-legacy-season1) and the creation of a [pandemic-legacy-s02](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pandemic-legacy-s02) or [pandemic-legacy-season2](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pandemic-legacy-season2). For example if the same question (let's say about a standard game mechanic) would have two separate answers depending on whether it is Season 1 or 2 then a new tag would be warranted. If the question would apply to both S01 and S02, than it should just be outlined in the body of the question and both tags can be used.

If the tag edit is going to be made, it should be done so sooner rather than later though. As of right now it looks like all the [pandemic-legacy](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pandemic-legacy) questions are about season 1, so a tag edit now would be a lot simpler than one after season 2 questions start appearing.

Update Spoilers for S02:

> After looking around a bit more, the games seem pretty different from each other. The rules may be similar and there will be some carry over, but the gameboards are completely different. I think they should be treated as two separate games

Comment: I think it will be less that questions would have different answers, and more that a question for one would be meaningless for the other. Things like roadblocks, relationships, and search parties might not exist at all. The roles are different. Even basic concepts like cures and outbreaks don't exist (at least with those names). Of course, the legacy aspect of it makes this somewhat speculation.

Comment: If the questions will only be relevant about one season and meaningless to the other than there isn't really a reason to create a new tag. The umbrella [tag:pandemic-legacy] will cover both with no confusion since it will apply only to one and not the other vs. slightly differently depending on season. Any edge cases can just be specified in the question body/title.

Comment: @Malco That makes sense on the surface, but "no confusion" might be an exaggeration. If these are effectively two different games, then using one tag for both is a bit like using the same tag for regular Pandemic and for Pandemic Legacy, or for Small World and Small World Underground. We usually have different tags for different games, so it's a little confusing to not do so here.

Comment: SPOILERS FOR S02 @Jefromi After looking around a bit more, the games seem pretty different from each other, rules may be similar and there will be some carry over, but the gameboards are completely different. I think they should be treated as two separate games.

Comment: That's not a spoiler. They are two distinct games!